# How do I add a UIview to an imageView while ensuring that the contents of the UIView are inside the it's frame?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, ios8, addsubview

I have a superview which contains a `ImageView`, a `testView`, and some buttons.  I created a `UIView` which contains  `ImageView2` and a `removebutton`.
When I add `UIView` to `UIImageView`, the contents of `UIView` are not in the frame of `UIView`.  Because of that, I cannot apply pan gesture recognizer.
I have tried to apply constraints and to change the frame and centre of `ImageView2`.

Below is the code I am using to create the above mentioned `UIView`.  How do I ensure that the contents of the `UIView` are visible in the frame of the `UIView`?

```
let rect = CGRect(x: self.imageView.center.x-30, y: self.imageView.center.y-30, width: 80, height: 80)

testview = UIView(frame: rect)
testview.layer.cornerRadius = testview.frame.width/2
testview.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
testview.clipsToBounds = true

imageView2 = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: testview.frame.minX+10, y: testview.frame.minY+10, width: 60, height: 60))

let rect2 = CGRect(x: self.testview.frame.maxX-17, y: self.testview.frame.minY, width: 20, height: 20)

removeButton = UIButton(frame: rect2)

removeButton.layer.cornerRadius = removeButton.frame.width/2

removeButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

removeButton.clipsToBounds = true

imageView2.layer.cornerRadius = imageView2.frame.width/2

imageView2.userInteractionEnabled = true

imageView2.clipsToBounds = true
testview.alpha = 0.3

imageView2.center = testview.center

imageView2.center = testview.center

testview.addSubview(imageView2)

testview.addSubview(removeButton)

testview.bringSubviewToFront(imageView2)

imageView.addSubview(testview)
```

Comment: "the contents of UIView are not in the frame of UIView" Not obvious what that means. Could you please explain what's wrong, a little more clearly?

Comment: subview(imageView) of uiview  are outside the frame/bounds of of uiview.
for eg if ui view has a frame of x:0,y:0,width : 80 ,height: 80 then the imageview is at x:200,y:200:width :60 height: 60

Comment: Do you understand the difference between frame and bounds?

Comment: Thanx matt for pointing me in the right direction :). Can you help in one more thing i.e I have selection hidesBottomBarWhen Pushed(in storyboard) this removes tab bar from view but it does that with a animation when the view appears. I dont want that animation , so is there a way i could do that in viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that lines like this do not do what you think:

```
let rect = CGRect(x: self.imageView.center.x-30, y: self.imageView.center.y-30, width: 80, height: 80)
// ... and ...
imageView2.center = testview.center
```

The `center` of a view is in its `frame` coordinates - it has to do with how the view is placed *in its superview*. But the position of a subview must be described in terms of its superviews `bounds`, not its `frame`. Its `bounds` are its *internal* coordinates, which is what you want.

Let's take the simplest case: how to center a subview in a superview. This is not the way:

```
imageView2.center = testview.center
```

You see the problem? `testview.center` is where `testview` is located *in its superview*; it is not the *internal* center of `testview`, which is what you want. The internal center of `testview` comes from its `bounds`. This is the way:

```
let c = CGPointMake(testview.bounds.midX, testview.bounds.midY)
imageView2.center = c
```